# How to make button clickable in JTable?

Tags: jtable, java-6

Here, I have a JTable with 11 columns. In that JTable 2 columns have buttons. The buttons are displayed but it is not clickable. How to make this buttons clickable?. The following is my code.

```
jTableANCUltrasonography = new com.sysvine.healthpractice.gui.component.HJTableSort();
    TableModelHP tm = new TableModelHP(columnList,1);
    this.jTableANCUltrasonography.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jTableANCUltrasonography.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    tm.setEditCol(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
    tm.setDataVector(new Object[][] { { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Save", "Delete" } }, new Object[] {"Date", "GA", "Prsn", "Placenta", "FM", "FH", "EFW", "Liq", "Impression", "Save", "Delete"});
    jTableANCUltrasonography.setModel(tm);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(0)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.leftInsetsCellRenderer); 
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(1)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.leftInsetsCellRenderer); 
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(2)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.leftInsetsCellRenderer);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(3)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.leftInsetsCellRenderer);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(4)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.leftInsetsCellRenderer);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(5)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.rightInsetsCellRenderer);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(6)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.rightInsetsCellRenderer);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(7)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.rightInsetsCellRenderer);
    ((jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumnModel()).getColumn(8)).setCellRenderer(TableRendererJLabel.rightInsetsCellRenderer);
    jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumn("Save").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
    jTableANCUltrasonography.getColumn("Delete").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
```

Help me. Thanks in advance.